# TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object multiprocessing

Tags: python, keras, multiprocessing, chess

I read all the questions of this error but none solved mine. (I really dont know)
when I use mp.Pool it outputs that error. ive looked into the errors like it on the github issues but there is no other issue that helped me nor has Rlock and not just "lock".
this is the code (im making a chess engine that the net is in python):

```
from numpy import array, mean
this_board = []
row = []
index = 0
for piece in str(L.board):
    if piece != " " and piece != "\n":
        index += 1
        row.append([get_piece_val(piece)])

    if index == 8:
        index = 0
        this_board.append(row)
        row = []
b = array([this_board])
if L.board.turn:
    p = mean(net.predict(b))
    L.update_value(p)
    #cache.update({L.board.fen():p})
else:
    p = mean(1-net.predict(b))
    L.update_value(p)
    #cache.update({L.board.fen():p})
```

I use mp.pool like this:

```
if len(batch) > batch_size:
    d = []
    for i in batch:
        d.append([i, net])
    with Pool(processes=THREADS) as p:
        p.map(update, d) # update is the function above, it takes L (i here) (the leaf node object) and the keras net. I tried the apply too and apply_async but both didnt work.
```

is this because net.predict is parallelized?

im using python3.8.6 and it says it doesnt have a version with `mp.__version__`

EDIT:
this article:
https://medium.com/@lih.verma/parallelizing-prediction-via-ml-dl-models-abf4a2032500
says keras cant be on multiprocessing because it is not multiprocessing safe.

I can do that parallel with compiling the model to c and then making predictions with that.

Comment: could you give an example of how you are using `mp.Pool`?

Comment: I edited the question with mp.Pool